# How to have 2 simultaneous spell-checker languages on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, language

Something that is routine to me is this:

> Right click > Spell-checker Options > Change language

I usually change this 10~30 times a day. It's really annoying to have that underlined red text with 'wrong' words of another idiom.

**I want to know if there is a way to have Chrome to use more than one spell checker at a time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome canary you can set a flag (option) for this like explained here:
http://thenextweb.com/google/2015/08/22/chrome-can-now-spellcheck-multiple-languages-simultaneouslyn

Comment: Sir, I must say that I will not use regular Chrome anymore. Chrome Canary from now on! And that is because of you. Thanks!

Comment: @Rodmentou Just in case you did not know, chrome canary is the crash-prone early release of chrome that they use to test out new features. **It is not intended for general browsing**. It gets its name from the [canary in a coal mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_sentinel), where a canary would be brought into coal mines and if it died miners would know that there was toxic gas.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielF I've searched why the 'Canary' name some minutes ago. haha. About that, I'm intending to use it until this function got shipped to the regular Chrome. I've got a crash on the first run already. And thanks, btw. :p

Comment: Thumbs up. Good luck. Dear to be different.